# Cross-class-capable extendable static analysis tool for java?

Tags: java, multithreading, annotations, static-analysis

I'm trying to write rules for detecting some errors in *annotated* multi-threaded java programs.  As a toy example, I'd like to detect if any method annotated with @ThreadSafe calls a method without such an annotation, without synchronization.  I'm looking for a tool that would allow me to write such a test.

I've looked at source analyzers, like CheckStyle and PMD, and they don't really have cross-class analysis capabilities.  Bytecode analysers, like FindBugs and JLint seem rather difficult to extend.

I'd settle for a solution to something even simpler, but posing the same difficulty: writing a *custom* rule that checks whether each overriden method is annotated with @Override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)?  It actually supports a set of [annotations for thread safety](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/annotations/doc/net/jcip/annotations/package-summary.html) (the same as those used in [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com)).  Also, you can write your own custom rules.  I'm not sure whether you can do cross-class analysis, but I believe so.

[Peter Ventjeer](http://pveentjer.wordpress.com) has a [concurrency checking tool](http://pveentjer.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/the-concurrency-detector/) (that uses ASM) to detect stuff like this.  I'm not sure if he's released it publicly but he might able to help you.

And I believe [Coverity's](http://www.coverity.com/) static/dynamic analysis tools for thread safety do checking like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do [cross-class analysis in PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtowritearule.html#I_want_to_implement_a_rule_that_analyse_more_than_the_class__) (though I've never used it for this specific purpose). I think it's possible using this visitor pattern that they document, though I'll leave the specifics to you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple tool to checkup on annotations is apt (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/ also part of Java 6 api in javax.annotation.processing) however this only has type information (ie I couldn't find a quick way to get at the inheritance hierarchy using the javax.lang.model api, however if you can load the class you can get that information using reflection).

Answer (score 0):

Try javap + regexes (eg. Perl)